# Swift - Not fires completion page animation and problems with delegate of UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, xcode6.1

Here is the parts of Swift code:

**ViewConroller.swift:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, SphereMenuDelegate, toggleMainBarDelegate {

...

func hideMainBar(i: Int) {
    println("Test1!")
    self.bottomBlack.frame.origin.y -= self.bottomBlack.frame.size.height
    self.imageView.frame.origin.y -= self.imageView.frame.size.height
}

...

let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageController") as UIPageViewController
    pageController.dataSource = self
    pageController.delegate = self;

if contentImages.count > 0 {
        let firstController = getItemController(0)!
        let startingViewControllers: NSArray = [firstController]
        pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers,
            direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward,
            animated: true,
            completion: {
                (Bool) in
                    println("Test2!")
            }
        )
    }

...
```

and **PageItemController.swift:**

```
protocol toggleMainBarDelegate {
    func hideMainBar(i:Int)
}

class PageItemController: UIViewController {

...

var delegate:toggleMainBarDelegate?

...

if(itemIndex > 0){
    self.delegate?.hideMainBar(itemIndex)
}

...
```

Project successfully builds and run, and working. But, it doesn't fire println Test1 and Test2 points at the moment of changing a page in pageviewcontroller!

Would be very happy if someone tell me where I'm wrong. Complete source are here - https://bitbucket.org/lenyapugachev/heart/src/805fbc723537?at=delegatesolvation

Comment: In one case, I think you have forgotten to set the `delegate` of the `PageItemController`.  You could amend `getItemController()` within `ViewController.swift` to ensure that the delegate is set to `self`.

Comment: but, I have a line `pageController.delegate = self`

Comment: That sets the delegate for the pageController, but each individual pageItemController needs its delegate set too - in the PageItemController class you have `self.delegate?.hideMainBar(itemIndex)` - self here refers to the pageItemController, not the pageController.

Comment: appreciate your time, man. it helps.